# redirect() helpers return a blank page after login in Laravel 8 and jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, controller

I have a step form in guest view in my Laravel app or I do a data processing and then I want to log a user create on the fly with the

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])
```

After that, I would like redirect the user to the dashboard view using the redirect() method.

But that return a blank page and I don't no why...

My method in my controller :

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            Auth::user();
            if (Auth::check()) {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard'); 
            } else {
                return view('welcome');
            }
        }
```

and my route :

```
Route::middleware('auth')->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

I have a 302 in my network tab and nothing in my DOM...

I use JetStream/ Fortify for authentification...

When I try to login manually with the login page, I have the same result, a blank page...

Thanks for your response

Comment: whats the current URL in the address bar?

Comment: Does the view/blade exist and has content? Any errors/warnings in laravel.log?

Comment: Yes the view exist and had content and any error in log... The current url after I submit the form stay on the url where I went when I call the form...

Comment: so the browser isn't following the redirect?

Comment: Ah no sorry, the cuurent url after I submit is '/dashboard' but with blank screen...

Comment: And I try to change the return in 'Hello World' instead the view() in callback method in route but I have already a blank screen...

Comment: It can be a cache problem , have you tried clearing cache ?

Comment: @JoLeBelge did you find a solution?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem... when I go to a non-existing route, I do see Laravel's 404 message.